# How to work with multiple datasets in p5.js?

Tags: p5.js

I want to create multiple line graphs with their own datasets into one p5.js sketch.
I created one line graph and do not know how to make another line graph to work with a different dataset.

https://editor.p5js.org/ariel.koh/sketches/VsRk3KxYp

I tried to create another preload table for my second graph but it did not work so I am still confused.

This was what I tried but I think it is not right, I never tried working with multiple datasets before so I am confused :(

```
let burnsdataset;
let canonattacksdataset;

function preload() {
// burns dataset
burnsdataset = loadTable("burns.csv", "csv", "header");

// canonattacks dataset
canonaattacksdataset = loadTable("canonattacks.csv", "csv", 
"header");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track loading the data.

The p5.js code you posted is a bit convoluted, here only a few examples:

- the year labels a manually drawn, for each chart (even though the data is contained in the csv files)
- if the text is simply drawn for the years but separate style, coordinate transformations, etc. are used then the `push()/pop()` call don't add anything.(e.g `push();let sbm = 'Saul Bass Movies';...`)
- the `drawLineGraph()` function is defined twice (which might get you into [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) bugs) and might be accidentally called within itself

No wonder you're confused.

I'd simplify as much as possible:

1. get back to loading and displaying one graph
2. load the second dataset (as you already correctly do above)
3. display the second graph

For example:

```js
// file -> duplicate and file -> save
// this sketch first before you
// start working on it.
//
//
//
// Graph from Data, Line graph example
//
// Slides:
// http://slides.com/sojamo/cid-3-2122/fullscreen#/12/5

let burnsdataset;
let canonattacksdataset;

function preload() {
  // burns dataset
  burnsdataset = loadTable("burns.csv", "csv", "header");
  canonaattacksdataset = loadTable("canonattacks.csv", "csv", "header");
  
}

function setup() {
  // if you add SVG as 3rd parameter and then
  // press s, the canvas will be saved as SVG file
  createCanvas(displayWidth, displayHeight, SVG);
}

function draw() {
  background(184, 37, 0);

  //bottom label title
  push();
  textSize(14);
  textFont("inconsolata");
  textStyle(BOLDITALIC);
  fill(243, 230, 214);
  text("Burns", 30, 20, 330, 150); // Text wraps within text box
  pop();

  //linegraph
  drawLineGraph({
    dataset: burnsdataset,
    column: 1,
    x: 30,
    y: 50,
    w: width - 1500,
    h: height - 900,
    lc: color(255, 255, 255),
    dc: color(169, 247, 111),
    thickness: 1.5,
    isCurve: true,
    isDots: true,
    isBackground: true,
    isLabel: true,
  });
  
  //bottom label title
  push();
  textSize(14);
  textFont("inconsolata");
  textStyle(BOLDITALIC);
  fill(243, 230, 214);
  text("Canon Attacks", 30, 250, 330, 150); // Text wraps within text box
  pop();
  
  //linegraph
  drawLineGraph({
    dataset: canonaattacksdataset,
    column: 1,
    x: 30,
    y: 280,
    w: width - 1500,
    h: height - 900,
    lc: color(255, 255, 255),
    dc: color(169, 247, 111),
    thickness: 1.5,
    isCurve: true,
    isDots: true,
    isBackground: true,
    isLabel: true,
  });
  
  
}



function drawLineGraph(theProps = {}) {
  let values = theProps.dataset.getColumn(theProps.column);
  let minValue = min(values); 
  let maxValue = max(values);

  let x = theProps.x || 0;
  let y = theProps.y || 0;
  let w = theProps.w || 400;
  let h = theProps.h || 300;
  let bg = theProps.bg || color(255, 40);
  let fg = theProps.fg || color(255, 120);
  let dc = theProps.dc || color(0, 120);
  let bc = theProps.bc || color(0, 120);
  let lc = theProps.lc || color(255);
  let thickness = theProps.thickness || 1;
  let isLabel = theProps.isLabel || false;
  let isCurve = theProps.isCurve || false;
  let isDots = theProps.isDots || false;
  let isBackground = theProps.isBackground || false;

  let spacing = w / (values.length - 1);
  let marginTopBottom = 20;

  // we will calcualte the x and y values for each
  // point first, because we need it later a couple
  // of times.
  let xx = [];
  let yy = [];
  let n = values.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    xx[i] = i * spacing;
    yy[i] = map(
      values[i],
      minValue,
      maxValue,
      -marginTopBottom,
      marginTopBottom - h
    );
  }

  push();
  translate(x, y);
  translate(0, h);

  // 1. draw background
  if (isBackground == true) {
    fill(bg);
    rect(0, 0, w, -h);

    // 2. draw grid
    noStroke();
    for (let i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
      // fill(255,i%2 == 0 ? 80:40);
      rect(xx[i], 0, 1, -h);
    }
  }

  // 3. draw curved line graph
  noFill();
  stroke(lc);
  strokeWeight(thickness);

  beginShape();
  if (isCurve == true) {
    vertex(xx[0], yy[0]);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let fn = isCurve == true ? curveVertex : vertex;
    fn(xx[i], yy[i]);
  }
  if (isCurve == true) {
    vertex(xx[n - 1], yy[n - 1]);
  }
  endShape();

  // 4. draw dot / label for each value
  noStroke();

  // finally lets draw the dots and 
  // labels if enabled
  let d = thickness + 8;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    
    push();
    translate(xx[i], yy[i]);
    
    if(isDots == true) {
      fill(bc);
      ellipse(0, 0, d + 4, d + 4);
      fill(dc);
      ellipse(0, 0, d, d);
    }
    
    if (isLabel == true) {
      fill(lc)
      rotate(-0.5);
      textSize(7);
      text(values[i], d, -d);
    }
    pop();
  }

  pop();
}
```

With that working you can focus on making the code nicer.
Taking the idea of ["don't repeat yourself(DRY)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) you can notice a few patterns that could be improved:

1. you try to not just draw the graph, but also also display the graph's
   label: perhaps the `drawLineGraph()` could include that
2. you seem to manually be drawing every single year label, even though the data is already in the dataset and the x position is already calculated to display the points of the graph

Tackling point 1 is fairly straight foward: simply move the label drawing instrunctions inside the function, handle the extra argument to get the label text and adjust coordinates so they're relative to the graph.

Here's a modified version of the above integrating label as part of the `drawLineGraph()` function:

```js
// file -> duplicate and file -> save
// this sketch first before you
// start working on it.
//
//
//
// Graph from Data, Line graph example
//
// Slides:
// http://slides.com/sojamo/cid-3-2122/fullscreen#/12/5

let burnsdataset;
let canonattacksdataset;

function preload() {
  // burns dataset
  burnsdataset = loadTable("burns.csv", "csv", "header");
  canonaattacksdataset = loadTable("canonattacks.csv", "csv", "header");
  
}

function setup() {
  // if you add SVG as 3rd parameter and then
  // press s, the canvas will be saved as SVG file
  createCanvas(displayWidth, displayHeight, SVG);
}

function draw() {
  background(184, 37, 0);

  //linegraph
  drawLineGraph({
    dataset: burnsdataset,
    label: "Burns",
    column: 1,
    x: 30,
    y: 50,
    w: width - 1500,
    h: height - 900,
    lc: color(255, 255, 255),
    dc: color(169, 247, 111),
    thickness: 1.5,
    isCurve: true,
    isDots: true,
    isBackground: true,
    isLabel: true,
  });
  
  //linegraph
  drawLineGraph({
    dataset: canonaattacksdataset,
    label: "Canon Attacks",
    column: 1,
    x: 30,
    y: 280,
    w: width - 1500,
    h: height - 900,
    lc: color(255, 255, 255),
    dc: color(169, 247, 111),
    thickness: 1.5,
    isCurve: true,
    isDots: true,
    isBackground: true,
    isLabel: true,
  });
  
  
}



function drawLineGraph(theProps = {}) {
  let values = theProps.dataset.getColumn(theProps.column);
  let minValue = min(values); 
  let maxValue = max(values);

  let x = theProps.x || 0;
  let y = theProps.y || 0;
  let w = theProps.w || 400;
  let h = theProps.h || 300;
  let bg = theProps.bg || color(255, 40);
  let fg = theProps.fg || color(255, 120);
  let dc = theProps.dc || color(0, 120);
  let bc = theProps.bc || color(0, 120);
  let lc = theProps.lc || color(255);
  let thickness = theProps.thickness || 1;
  let isLabel = theProps.isLabel || false;
  let isCurve = theProps.isCurve || false;
  let isDots = theProps.isDots || false;
  let isBackground = theProps.isBackground || false;
  let label = theProps.label || "";

  let spacing = w / (values.length - 1);
  let marginTopBottom = 20;
  
  //bottom label title
  push();
  textSize(14);
  textFont("inconsolata");
  textStyle(BOLDITALIC);
  fill(243, 230, 214);
  text(label, x, y + h + marginTopBottom * 0.5, w, h); // Text wraps within text box
  pop();


  // we will calculate the x and y values for each
  // point first, because we need it later a couple
  // of times.
  let xx = [];
  let yy = [];
  let n = values.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    xx[i] = i * spacing;
    yy[i] = map(
      values[i],
      minValue,
      maxValue,
      -marginTopBottom,
      marginTopBottom - h
    );
  }

  push();
  translate(x, y);
  translate(0, h);

  // 1. draw background
  if (isBackground == true) {
    fill(bg);
    rect(0, 0, w, -h);

    // 2. draw grid
    noStroke();
    for (let i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
      // fill(255,i%2 == 0 ? 80:40);
      rect(xx[i], 0, 1, -h);
    }
  }

  // 3. draw curved line graph
  noFill();
  stroke(lc);
  strokeWeight(thickness);

  beginShape();
  if (isCurve == true) {
    vertex(xx[0], yy[0]);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let fn = isCurve == true ? curveVertex : vertex;
    fn(xx[i], yy[i]);
  }
  if (isCurve == true) {
    vertex(xx[n - 1], yy[n - 1]);
  }
  endShape();

  // 4. draw dot / label for each value
  noStroke();

  // finally lets draw the dots and 
  // labels if enabled
  let d = thickness + 8;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    
    push();
    translate(xx[i], yy[i]);
    
    if(isDots == true) {
      fill(bc);
      ellipse(0, 0, d + 4, d + 4);
      fill(dc);
      ellipse(0, 0, d, d);
    }
    
    if (isLabel == true) {
      fill(lc)
      rotate(-0.5);
      textSize(7);
      text(values[i], d, -d);
    }
    pop();
  }

  pop();
}
```

And here's a modified version of the above that renders the labels on the x axis (year):

```js
// file -> duplicate and file -> save
// this sketch first before you
// start working on it.
//
//
//
// Graph from Data, Line graph example
//
// Slides:
// http://slides.com/sojamo/cid-3-2122/fullscreen#/12/5

let burnsdataset;
let canonattacksdataset;

function preload() {
  // burns dataset
  burnsdataset = loadTable("burns.csv", "csv", "header");
  // canon attacks dataset
  canonaattacksdataset = loadTable("canonattacks.csv", "csv", "header");
  
}

function setup() {
  // if you add SVG as 3rd parameter and then
  // press s, the canvas will be saved as SVG file
  createCanvas(displayWidth, displayHeight, SVG);
  drawPlots();
}

function drawPlots() {
  background(184, 37, 0);

  // burnsdataset linegraph
  drawLineGraph({
    dataset: burnsdataset,
    label: "Burns",
    xColumn: 0,
    yColumn: 1,
    x: 30,
    y: 50,
    w: width - 1500,
    h: height - 900,
    lc: color(255, 255, 255),
    dc: color(169, 247, 111),
    thickness: 1.5,
    isCurve: true,
    isDots: true,
    isBackground: true,
    isLabel: true,
  });
  
  // canonaattacksdataset linegraph
  drawLineGraph({
    dataset: canonaattacksdataset,
    label: "Canon Attacks",
    xColumn: 0,
    yColumn: 1,
    x: 30,
    y: 300,
    w: width - 1500,
    h: height - 900,
    lc: color(255, 255, 255),
    dc: color(169, 247, 111),
    thickness: 1.5,
    isCurve: true,
    isDots: true,
    isBackground: true,
    isLabel: true,
  });
  
}

function drawLineGraph(theProps = {}) {
  let values = theProps.dataset.getColumn(theProps.yColumn);
  let minValue = min(values); 
  let maxValue = max(values);
  
  let labels = theProps.dataset.getColumn(theProps.xColumn);
  
  let x = theProps.x || 0;
  let y = theProps.y || 0;
  let w = theProps.w || 400;
  let h = theProps.h || 300;
  let bg = theProps.bg || color(255, 40);
  let fg = theProps.fg || color(255, 120);
  let dc = theProps.dc || color(0, 120);
  let bc = theProps.bc || color(0, 120);
  let lc = theProps.lc || color(255);
  let thickness = theProps.thickness || 1;
  let isLabel = theProps.isLabel || false;
  let isCurve = theProps.isCurve || false;
  let isDots = theProps.isDots || false;
  let isBackground = theProps.isBackground || false;
  let label = theProps.label || "";

  let spacing = w / (values.length - 1);
  let marginTopBottom = 20;
  
  // y position for labels (e.g. years)
  let labelsY = marginTopBottom * 0.5;
  //bottom label title
  push();
  textSize(14);
  textFont("inconsolata");
  textStyle(BOLDITALIC);
  fill(243, 230, 214);
  text(label, x, y - marginTopBottom, w, h); // Text wraps within text box
  pop();


  // we will calculate the x and y values for each
  // point first, because we need it later a couple
  // of times.
  let xx = [];
  let yy = [];
  let n = values.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    xx[i] = i * spacing;
    yy[i] = map(
      values[i],
      minValue,
      maxValue,
      -marginTopBottom,
      marginTopBottom - h
    );
  }

  push();
  translate(x, y);
  translate(0, h);

  // 1. draw background
  if (isBackground == true) {
    fill(bg);
    rect(0, 0, w, -h);

    // 2. draw grid
    noStroke();
    for (let i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
      // fill(255,i%2 == 0 ? 80:40);
      rect(xx[i], 0, 1, -h);
    }
  }

  // 3. draw curved line graph
  noFill();
  stroke(lc);
  strokeWeight(thickness);

  beginShape();
  if (isCurve == true) {
    vertex(xx[0], yy[0]);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let fn = isCurve == true ? curveVertex : vertex;
    fn(xx[i], yy[i]);
    // label per data point
    push();
    noStroke();
    fill(255);
    textSize(9);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(labels[i], xx[i], labelsY);
    pop();
  }
  if (isCurve == true) {
    vertex(xx[n - 1], yy[n - 1]);
  }
  endShape();

  // 4. draw dot / label for each value
  noStroke();

  // finally lets draw the dots and 
  // labels if enabled
  let d = thickness + 8;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    
    push();
    translate(xx[i], yy[i]);
    
    if(isDots == true) {
      fill(bc);
      ellipse(0, 0, d + 4, d + 4);
      fill(dc);
      ellipse(0, 0, d, d);
    }
    
    if (isLabel == true) {
      fill(lc)
      rotate(-0.5);
      textSize(7);
      text(values[i], d, -d);
    }
    pop();
  }

  pop();
}

// if you want to use the SVG export
// option, go to setup and enable SVG mode
function keyPressed() {
  if (key === "s") {
    saveSVG("line-graph.svg");
  }
}
```

There's one slight detail snuck in there: I've renamed `draw()` to `drawPlots()` and called it once from `setup()`. That is to render the plots a single time since they don't change and save CPU resources. If you do plan to have some sort interation changing these graphs then you should use `draw()`.